# Trajectory of a Charged Particle in a uniform magnetic field in the context of mechanically-enforced sinusoidal motion

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electricity, plasma-physics, charge-carrier

I want to find out what would happen to the trajectory of a charged particle, say a proton moving at an angle in a uniform magnetic field if its motion were mechanically altered by a physical barrier.

Without any barrier altering the trajectory, the problem I have in mind is pretty straightforward (see fig. 1.). The particle would simply describe a helical path.

Now, suppose (see fig. 2.) that there was a barrier or rather two barriers running parallel to the initial velocity vector (ignore any electrical or other attributes of the barriers, they're simply the path the proton cannot deviate from, if you want to imagine them in 3-d, just think of them as being akin to a ripple in water). What would the proton's trajectory look like?

Further, (see fig. 3), and to the actual point of the question, what would happen if these barriers had an undulating sinusoidal path? What would the particle's trajectory look like then?

Would it still exhibit helical or cycloid motion or something else?

I'd be very thankful to see a diagram of what would happen. Thanks!

[image: fig. 1.]

[image: fig. 2.]

[image: fig. 3.]

Comment: *Note* due to the actual physical properties of protons, if you were being literalistic, you could simply rephrase the question in terms of cations, while simply ignoring the fluid mechanics. Or just address it in terms of the shape of a current (made of countless particles) itself.

Comment: You must define the interactions between the barrier and the proton. Is it a hard wall?

Comment: @Shaktyai, yes, it is a hard, perfectly rigid wall, with the shape of ripples in water. Thank you!

Comment: @Shaktyai, also the wall is frictionless, and collisions are inelastic. Basically, the wall is simply meant to enforce the particular pattern of motion outlined.  If there is a way to do this, you could just say the proton has to follow this path and get rid of the wall.

Comment: Subatomic particles don't tend to just bounce off walls if they are charged like this, do they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a specular reflection to calculate the new velocity after the collision:

$$ \begin{cases}v^{f} _{//} =  v^{i} _{//}\\v^{f} _{ \bot } =  -v^{i} _{ \bot }\end{cases}$$

Where $v_{//}$ is the tangential velocity at the point of contact between the proton and the wall and $v_{\bot}$ is the perpendicular velocity.

During free flight, between two collisions, use the classical helicoidal trajectory.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.